# -bash: cucumber: command not found

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bundler

I am new to Cucumber and tried to run it for the first time on Mac.

I installed ruby and with 
    bundle install 
it installed cucumber 3.1.2
But for some reason it says

```
command not found
```

In other threads it said I have to change the path but I didn't understand which one and how. If someone could provide detailed infos I would be very grateful. thanks

cucumber is installed:

```
      * cucumber (3.1.2)
         Summary: cucumber-3.1.2
         Homepage: https://cucumber.io/
         Path: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2
```

so come these information when I try

```
gem env
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
      - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.4 (2019-08-28 patchlevel 104) [x86_64-darwin18]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
      - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/filip/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
      - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
      - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/filip/.gem/specs
      - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.4_2/etc
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-darwin-18
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
         - /Users/filip/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
         - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.4_2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - https://rubygems.org/
      - SHELL PATH:
         - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
         - /usr/local/bin
         - /usr/bin
         - /bin
         - /usr/sbin
         - /sbin
         - /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to use an additional tool to run and manage rubies rather than using the system ruby (on OSX this is at `/usr/local/bin/ruby`) or a ruby installed by something like Homebrew.

Have a look at rbenv https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

or

RVM https://rvm.io

before you try and resolve this issue. These tools allow you to setup isolated instances of ruby where its easy to ensure that you gems are installed in the correct location, and your path does not interfere in their retrieval.

You may be able to resolve your current issue in your environment by running `bundle exec cucumber`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I installed another ruby version and bundle exec cucumber worked for me!